# Problem in using 'href=""' attribute inside listItem

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having listview in a html code. I'm populating the list view dynamically inside javascript. I have show a pdf after clicking the list item. i used anchor tag inside list item('li'). Here is the code.

```
$('div').live('pageshow',function(event, ui){

      var parent = document.getElementById('listview')
      var listItem = document.createElement('li');
        listItem.setAttribute('id','listitem');
        listItem.innerHTML = "<a href="Contacts.pdf" target="_BLANK" >ITEm</a>";
parent.appendChild(listItem);
     });
```

But its not working. In the browser, the list item is not shown in the list. If i remove " href="Contacts.pdf" target="_BLANK" " then it works fine. 
What is wrong in this? Im using this code with jquery-mobile alpha2. Pls help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the HTML that is generated?

Comment: Your code will generate invalid HTML, as you'll have many items with the same ID - really bad idea. If you don't need the ID then just remove that line otherwise add some unique value like the amount of current list items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double quote problem

Replace this line

```
 listItem.innerHTML = "<a href='Contacts.pdf' target='_BLANK' >ITEm</a>";
```

use single quote inside the double quote.

Answer (score 2):

To use quotation marks inside the string, you have to escape them using backslash:

```
listItem.innerHTML = "<a href=\"Contacts.pdf\" target=\"_BLANK\" >ITEm</a>";
```

I find it easier to use apostrophes around the string when createing HTML code, that way the quotation marks doesn't need escaping:

```
listItem.innerHTML = '<a href="Contacts.pdf" target="_BLANK" >ITEm</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have it all in one line:

```
$("#listview").append("<li><a href=\"Contacts.pdf\" target=\"_BLANK\">ITEm</a></li>");
```